# What is the correct docstring for unicode/str parameter in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a method that accepts a `unicode` parameter in Python 2, but in Python 3 it accepts a `str`.
I am wondering how I should write the sphinx docstring for this function:
`:param unicode text:` or `:param str text:` or a seperate documentation for Python 2 and Python 3?

Example:

```python
def myfunction(text):
    """Do something with text
    :param unicode text: Must be unicode
    :rtype: unicode
    :raises TypeError: If text is not a unicode
    """
    if PY2 and not isinstance(text, unicode):
        raise TypeError("Argument 'text' must be unicode")
    ...
    return text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there's any easier way that [`six.text_type`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.text_type).

But couple of thing on top of that:
 - please double-check if you actually need `unicode` and not `basestring`, this looks non-pythonic
 - if you're in the middle of migration to PY3 and this is compatibility thing — just go with `str` and document for PY3
 - write type for PY3 and clarify difference in description. Docstrings is 100% for humans, just think if its easier to read 1 note in rare case or decypher weird compatibility type every time

Comment: I am moving from only Python 3 to supporting 2.7 and 3. I thought it would be better to let the user handle the decoding and just accept unicode like in Python 3